# Intermittent scrambled panels when browsing on Chrome for Android 7.0

Tags: chrome-for-android, screen, lg

The client has intermittent scrambled panels when browsing on Chrome for Android 7.0. They display randomly as pages are loaded.

[image: Mobile screen issue 01] [image: Mobile screen issue 02] [image: Mobile screen issue 03]

<sup>Image resized. Click for the full image.</sup>

The phone in use is LG K8 (2017)

Is this simply a breakdown in hardware or could there be a security issue?

Comment: I think this is happening because of a hardware issue. perhaps the screen's IC is broken

Answer (score 0):

Recently started having the same issue, and I'm not the only one, according to Google search. Seems to be a software issue with Chrome. The only solution so far has been to install Chrome beta version